# error when running 'cordova emulate android' in comand prompt

Tags: android, cordova, command-prompt

I get this error when i'm trying to run the emulator (this is a basic project made with 'cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld'.
Also the cordova build command isn't working

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My solution after hours of searching , my Android_HOME system variable wasn't linked to my sdk folder but to the normal android folder .